# How to retrieve feed asynchronously from a file in the computer?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, windows-runtime, winrt-async

I want to make an app to show news inside a textbox from an rss feed.. But the problem is rss feed contains and error in it's xml codes. Therefor Syndicationclient class can not be used properly. So I've made my program to get the xml text from the rssfeed and write the rss feed inside a textfile in the Application's local folder..

But the problem is I dont know how to retrieve feed to the Syndication feed from that file.. And here is the code I've tried..

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://lankadeepa.lk/index.php/maincontroller/breakingnews_rss");
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        string data = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        textBox1.Text = data.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"</admin:generatoragent>", @"</admin:generatorAgent>");

        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("xmlcodes.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, textBox1.Text);



        string feedpath =  file.Path.ToString();



        SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
        SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri(feedpath));

        textBox1.Text = "";

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            textBox1.Text += item.Title.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + item.Summary.Text.ToString() +
                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

What's the wrong with my code ? or SyndicationFeed class cant retrieve feed from a file ?

PS:

And Im not sure if I corrected the xml error in the feed properly.. Here is the feed..
"http://lankadeepa.lk/index.php/maincontroller/breakingnews_rss"

In the first lines it contains a xml tag like this..

```
<admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://www.codeigniter.com/" />
```

here hundreds of xml codes and

`</admin:generatoragent>`

I dont know well about xml. But I would like to know about this too..
In XAML here is how code writes..

```
<tag> </tag>
```

or

```
<tag />
```

no closing tag..

But in this feed the first tag it contains  and then it contains a closing tag too.. It must be wrong. doesnt it ?
and the first one is "generatorAgent" and the second one is "generatoragent" the letter A is changed to lowecase letter in the second.. does xml is a case sensitive language ?

PS: And here is the error I got..

---

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)

---

Comment: "What's the wrong with my code ?"  What isn't working?  are you getting an exception? the "PS" questions are also better suited for another question.

Comment: @JohnGardner "SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri(feedpath));" this line isnt working.... I edited the post... Thanks

Comment: so the error tells you that the file uri syntax is incorrect. you have `feedpath =  file.Path.ToString();` which may or may not be a valid path as a uri.

Comment: @JohnGardner So is there any other way to retrieve feed from a file ?

Comment: you never answered the question. what is the string you get back?  is it just c:\something\something.xml? that might not be a valid uri for RetrieveFeedAsync.  Maybe file://c:/something/something.xml would be?  I don't know, i'm just surmising here

Comment: @John Gardner  string is feedpath.. It contains the path to the StorageFile file..

StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("xmlcodes.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

Therefor in my computer the path would be.. **



C:\Users\Astro\AppData\Local\Packages\4f3f759f-8612-4a87-8a71-d139cafbb8a0_xfk21ev7ernpw\LocalState\xmlcodes.txt

thanks

Comment: like I said, have you tried turning that into a *valid file* uri, like `file://c:/users/astro/whatever/whatever/whatever` ?

Comment: @JohnGardner This is winrt.. so a path like c:\users\astro\folder\file doesnt work with this program.. :( Application's folders are the only folders that winrt app can access without users permissions..

Comment: i know this is winrt. but you are also talking about a method that *takes a `uri`*  have you verified that `c:\whatever\whatever\` is a *valid URI*.  Not a valid PATH, a valid URI.